# Share Redis pool between Sidekiq & Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, sidekiq

What is the best practice to share a Redis connection pool between Rails & Sidekiq ?

I've done that in an initializer :

```
Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  pool = ConnectionPool.new(size: 1, timeout: 5) { Redis.new(host: redis_config['host'], port: redis_config['port'], db: redis_config['database']) }
  config.redis  = pool
  Redis.current = pool
end

Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  pool = ConnectionPool.new(size: 10, timeout: 5) { Redis.new(host: redis_config['host'], port: redis_config['port'], db: redis_config['database']) }
  config.redis  = pool
  Redis.current = pool
  config.server_middleware do |chain|
    chain.add Kiqstand::Middleware
  end
end
```

But setting the Rails Redis pool in the Sidekiq block is not very clean...
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a look into Sidekiq sources, Sidekiq.server? method should be a better option.
I've change the initializer code for this :

```
# Redis config
Redis.current = ConnectionPool.new(size: (Sidekiq.server? ? 15 : 1), timeout: 5) do 
  Redis.new host: redis_config['host'], port: redis_config['port'], db: redis_config['database']
end

# Sidekiq config
Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = Redis.current
end

Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = Redis.current
  config.server_middleware do |chain|
    chain.add Kiqstand::Middleware
  end
end
```